# Truncating text and adding an ellipsis in CSS

Tags: css, ellipsis

I'm attempting to truncate a paragraph of text and adding an ellipsis after to indicate there is more content.

I attempted to use the CSS property `text-overflow:ellipsis` - however looking at examples of this it seems it is only possible with the use of `no-wrap` and thus it can only be used on single lines of text, so not appropriate for truncating a paragraph.

I then came up with another soltuion, which is *almost* correct but has just one problem...

So instead of truncating using the `ellipsis` property, I truncated the old fashioned way by using `overflow:hidden` and setting a `max-height`

```
.tourItem .tourInfo
{
max-height: 110px;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
}
```

And then to create the neat ellipsis I used `:after`

```
.tourItem .tourInfo:after {content:'...';}
```

This seems like the right way however I have run into two problems...

1. The `overflow:hidden` means that the `:after` content doesn't show. But it's required as it is what controls the truncated text!
2. The ellipsis (if you take off the `overflow:hidden`) is shown underneath the section of text. I need it to seem like it is part of the line of text...

[JS Fiddle to help](http://cdpn.io/vyjFD)

Comment: If your happy to go down the plugin route, i'd recommend checking out the [jQuery dodotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) which can help with this.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/rLhcjcn1/), where ellipsis is added to the paragraph using CSS only. You can customize the background according to the requirements/needs.

Here's the code:

```css
.tourItem {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  width: 244px;
  height: 7em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tourItem .tourInfo {
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 204px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  font-size: .95em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: justify;
}

.tourItem .tourInfo:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
}

.tourItem .tourInfo:before {
  content: '...';
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 20px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 38%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 99%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0)), color-stop(38%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)), color-stop(99%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 38%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 99%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 38%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 99%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 38%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 99%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(224, 224, 224, 0) 0%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 38%, rgba(224, 224, 224, 1) 99%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00e0e0e0', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tourItem ">
  <div class="tourInfo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use -webkit-line-clamp, which is a webkit/blink brower private property

```css
.ellipsis1 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='ellipsis1'>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
```

and if you want to custom ellipsis text, use this pure css method:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {/*for test*/
    0% { width: 622px }
    50% { width: 311px }
    100% { width: 622px }
}
.ellipsis {
    max-height: 40px;/* h*n */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;

    -webkit-animation: ellipsis ease 5s infinite;/*for test*/
    /**
    overflow: visible;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .content {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    font-size: 50px;/* w */
    line-height: 20px;/* line-height h */
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;/* max row number n */
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ellipsis .text {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
.ellipsis .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    /**
    overflow: visible;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .overlay:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;

    /**
    background: lightgreen;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .placeholder {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;/* h*n */

    /**
    background: lightblue;
    /**/
}
.ellipsis .more {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;/* -h */
    left: -50px;/* -w */
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    width: 50px;/* width of the .more w */
    height: 20px;/* h */
    font-size: 14px;

    /**
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: orange;
    /**/
}
```

```html
<div class='ellipsis'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='text'>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
        <div class='overlay'>
            <div class='placeholder'></div>
            <div class='more'>...more</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to make something like this?

```
<div class="content-ovh">
   <p class="text">Your text</p>
   <a href="#">More</a>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
.content-ovh .text{
    witdh: yoursize px;
    height: yoursize px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as per the content I have. I need an ellipsis, not a read more button.

Comment: Ok sorry, and using your second option if you assign to the <p> element the property "display:inline;" it will work. (Just try on your codepen)

Answer (score 0):

I swapped some styles around and it works like this! I moved the `max-height` and `overflow` to the `<p>` tag instead of the div. This way the div automaticly takes the correct height of the paragraph and now you can use the :after on the `div`, and hide the `:after` on hover. Next to this I also positioned the "dots" to the right position.

**CSS**

```
.tourInfo {
    width:150px;
    display: block;
}

.tourInfo:after { /* position the dots */
     position:relative;
     background-color:white;
     left:138px;
     top:-16px;
    content:'...';
}
.tourInfo p{
    color:#666;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden; /* overflow hidden on the <p> instead of the div */
    max-height: 110px;
}

.tourInfo:hover:after {
    display:none; /* hide after on hover */
}

.tourInfo:hover p {
    max-height:100%; /* change max-height on hover */
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/jPM4R/3/

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to wrap `tourInfo`. This way you can give `tourInfo` a percentage width to allow room for the ellipsis.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bacon">
    <span class="tourInfo">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bacon{
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

.tourInfo{
    height: 110px;
    width: 85%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tourInfo:after{
    content: '...';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: 18px;
}
```

This could probably be refined a bit but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a jquery plugin for truncating a text inside a HTML container :

https://github.com/AlirezaAsadi/truncatie

Truncatie is a jquery plugin that limit size of text by lines within a html container

**usagex**

```
  $('big-text').truncatie({
       elipsis: '...',
       max: 2 /* Number of lines limitation */
   });
```

**# Input**

```
 Truncatie is a jquery plugin
 that limit size of text by 
 lines within a html container
```

**# Outeput**

```
 Truncatie is a jquery plugin
 that limit size of text by..
```

Comment: Some sample code would be nice to explain the solution rather than just a link to a package as links can change or be removed.